# How can I cleanup files & directories in Azure Local Storage after a file begins streaming to the browser?

Tags: azure, asynchronous, local-storage, filestream, httpresponse

BACKGROUND:  I'm making use of Azure Local Storage.  This is supposed to be treated as "volatile" storage.  First of all, how long do the files & directories that I create persist on the Web Role Instances (there are 2, in my case)?  Do I need to worry about running out of storage if I don't do cleanup on those files/directories after each user is done with it?  What I'm doing is I'm pulling multiple files from a separate service, storing them in Azure Local Storage, compressing them into a zip file and storing that zip file, and then finally file streaming that zip file to the browser.

THE PROBLEM:  This all works beautifully except for one minor hiccup.  The file seems to stream to the browser asynchronously.  So what happens is that an exception gets thrown when I try to delete the zipped file from azure local storage afterward since it is still in the process of streaming to the browser.  What would be the best approach to forcing the deletion process to happen AFTER the file is completely streamed to the browser?

Here is my code:

```
                using (Service.Company.ServiceProvider CONNECT = new eZ.Service.CompanyConnect.ServiceProvider())
            {
                // Iterate through all of the files chosen
                foreach (Uri fileId in fileIds)
                {
                    // Get the int file id value from the uri
                    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"e[B|b]://[^\/]*/\d*/(\d*)");
                    string id_str = rex.Match(fileId.ToString()).Groups[1].Value;
                    int id = int.Parse(id_str);

                    // Get the file object from eB service from the file id passed in
                    eZ.Data.File f = new eZ.Data.File(CONNECT.eZSession, id);
                    f.Retrieve("Header; Repositories");

                    string _fileName = f.Name;

                    try
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            f.ContentData = new eZ.ContentData.File(f, stream);

                            // After the ContentData is created, hook into the event
                            f.ContentData.TransferProgressed += (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.Percentage); };

                            // Now do the transfer, the event will fire as blocks of data is read
                            int bytesRead;
                            f.ContentData.OpenRead();
                            // Open the Azure Local Storage file stream
                            using (azure_file_stream = File.OpenWrite(curr_user_path + _fileName))
                            {
                                while ((bytesRead = f.ContentData.Read()) > 0)
                                {
                                    // Write the chunk to azure local storage
                                    byte[] buffer = stream.GetBuffer();
                                    azure_file_stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                    stream.Position = 0;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        throw e;
                        //Console.WriteLine("The following error occurred:  " + e);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        f.ContentData.Close();
                    }
                } // end of foreach block

            } // end of eB using block

            string sevenZipDllPath = Path.Combine(Utilities.GetCurrentAssemblyPath(), "7z.dll");
            Global.logger.Info(string.Format("sevenZipDllPath: {0}", sevenZipDllPath));
            SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(sevenZipDllPath);

            var compressor = new SevenZipCompressor
            {
                ArchiveFormat = OutArchiveFormat.Zip,
                CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Fast
            };

            // Compress the user directory
            compressor.CompressDirectory(webRoleAzureStorage.RootPath + curr_user_directory, curr_user_package_path + "Package.zip");

            // stream Package.zip to the browser
            httpResponse.BufferOutput = false;
            httpResponse.ContentType = Utilities.GetMIMEType("BigStuff3.mp4");
            httpResponse.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Package.zip");

            azure_file_stream = File.OpenRead(curr_user_package_path + "Package.zip");
            azure_file_stream.CopyTo(httpResponse.OutputStream);
            httpResponse.End();

            // Azure Local Storage cleanup
            foreach (FileInfo file in user_directory.GetFiles())
            {
                file.Delete();
            }
            foreach (FileInfo file in package_directory.GetFiles())
            {
                file.Delete();
            }
            user_directory.Delete();
            package_directory.Delete();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you simply run a job on the machine that cleans up files after say a day of their creation?  This could be as simple as a batch file in the task scheduler or a separate thread started from WebRole.cs.
You can even use [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com) to auto-re-image your instance if the local space drops below a certain threshold

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I will definitely take a look at this AzureWatch.

Answer (score 1):

Could you place the files (esp. the final compressed one that the users download) in Windows Azure blob storage?  The file could be made public, or create a Shared Access Signature so that only the persons you provide the URL to could download it.  Placing the files in blob storage for download could alleviate some pressures on the web server.

Comment: That's actually the preferred long term solution.  This is just a temporary fix for now.